# javascript function to convert rows into columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to search for a required solution and help but really couldn't find something to write. I need this JavaScript function to do the following.

I have the following set of lines.

```
AAAAAAA
BBBBBBB
CCCCCCC
DDDDDDD
```

And I need to convert the above data into columns so the output would be like this.

```
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
```

That means the rows will be converted into columns.

Anyone can help with a JavaScript or jQuery function to get the results?

Comment: What format is this in? Are they 4 separate arrays? Are they printed out into 4 different rows of an html table?

Comment: is this array or string?

Comment: this is a test question actually for an assignment given. See the actual function question here. http://pastebin.com/kEGBzJzV - see #1. Text Blocking section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this using **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method

```js
var data = `AAAAAAA
BBBBBBB
CCCCCCC
DDDDDDD`;

var res = [];

data.split('\n').forEach(function(v) {
  v.split('').forEach(function(v1, i) {
    res[i] = (res[i] || '') + v1;
  })
});

console.log(res.join('\n'));
```

---

If both input and output are in array format then you can avoid the **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and **[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** methods

```js
var data = [
  'AAAAAAA',
  'BBBBBBB',
  'CCCCCCC',
  'DDDDDDD'
]

var res = [];

data.forEach(function(v) {
  v.split('').forEach(function(v1, i) {
    res[i] = (res[i] || '') + v1;
  })
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Per the requirement, your data var is a string. It needs to be an array.

Comment: this works, but when I print this in browser, it is not preserving the line breaks. and displaying all the values horizontally. any idea?

Comment: thanks. but where do I place join('<br/>') ? I placed it after the function brackets and it broke.

Comment: Thank you so much. that works. one more question. how do I make this whole thing as a function so I can supply different arguments to it instead of fixed AAAABBBB and so forth?

Comment: @RockingNinja : put them inside an array and pass array as argument.... then generate and return the result array...

Answer (score 0):

There may be better solutions than this, Try this:

```
var data = ["AAAAAAA",
            "BBBBBBB",
            "CCCCCCC",
            "DDDDDDD"];

var output = [];
data.map(function(a){
    for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++){
          if(!output[i])
              output[i] = "";
         output[i] += a[i];
    }
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the requirement in the question, this will do it:

```
var arr = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"];
var result = ['', '', ''];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var str = arr[i].split('');
    for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
        result[j] += str[j];
    }
}
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = ["AAAAAAA",
  "BBBBBBB",
  "CCCCCCC",
  "DDDDDDD"
];

var mapedData = data[0].split('').map(function(string, i) {
  return data.map(function(string1, i1) {
    return string1.charAt(i);
  }).join('');
});

console.log('required data ---', mapedData);
```